# How to delete message in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was just looking how to delete a message in discord in discord.py
i tries one code before but it not seems to work, I also tried reading discord's official documentation but that also not seem to work so that's why I need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i got the answer
for deleting a channel use

```
await message.channel.delete()
```

for deleting a message use

```
await message.delete()
```